# can't send/receive emails anymore in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, imap

I'm using Outlook as my email client and have an IMAP acccount. I had to change my password and now send/receive emails doesn't work anymore. I updated my account and I know the new password is correct, because I can get to my mails using webmail (Bluehost).
In desperation I already deleted the account and wanted to re-create it, but it again failed on the password issue.
Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: In desperation I already deleted the account and wanted to re-create it, but it again failed on the password issue. ----- Ask your Email vendor / ISP.  That is what I do for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the impact of the stored credential, please try the following steps:

```
1. clear Outlook credentials:
```

[image]

```
 2.Create a new profile(Control Panel>Mail>Show Profiles>add) and add your IMAP account.
```

Comment: Looked promising, but credentials list no Outlook/Office items :-(. Thanks for your reply anyway. HAND

Comment: What about creating a new profile (Control Panel>Mail>Show Profiles>add) and adding you IMAP account again?

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Comment: Solved! Thanks a bunch